# MYSQL table suggestions

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to MySQL and PHP. I am having issues wrapping my mind around how to accomplish something. I am building a site that has basically a forum style post page. Users enter text into a textarea which then posts that text along with a timestamp and $_SESSION['Username'] into a MySQL table titled "campaigns." So the table has postEntry, postName and postDate rows currently.

On this same page that I have the form, I then display the entire contents of the campaigns table into a div. So it can show each post in descending order.

This has been working great for me, but I am now trying to look at the bigger picture and am thinking this is not a good way to do what I need. I basically need the ability to have an endless amount of "campaigns" each with their own set of posts. Then give the user the ability to select which campaign they want to view and show corresponding posts for that campaign in the div.

So the real question is: Is there a way to do this with just one table. Or would each campaign need it's own table in the database?

Comment: The number of tables in a database are static - just read about third normal form. If you start creating tables on the fly you will have lots of trouble. Performance becomes problematic along with storage considerations.

Comment: Maybe you should read this: http://databases.about.com/od/specificproducts/a/normalization.htm

Comment: Neither option is quite correct, but certainly not the latter. See normalization. It's a tricky concept, but a vital one.

Comment: I will definitely read up on this, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `campaign_id` to the `POST` table and viola!

**edit:** more info:

you need one table for the campaign like so:

```
Campaign
-------------
campaign_id
name
```

then you need another one for all the posts

```
post
-------------
post_id
campaign_id
post_time
name
```

this way, each post is associated to a specific named campaign.

Comment: The table is campaigns and the post content is within this table. So I am not totally sure what you mean by this. Could you explain a little further?

Comment: Ok so you are saying have separate table for campaigns and for posts and then somehow join them? I know MySQL has a way to JOIN, but have not read up on it yet.

Comment: Ok this gives me some hope. Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: On the IDs. Should I just make them INT type
?